# Comparing a variable with a string in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
 male(X) :- (X=='john') ; (X=='dexter').
```

But now whenever I type the query male(X) and whenever X is unified with 'john' or 'dexter' it displays false whereas it should give true. Could Someone help?

Comment: These are atoms, not strings. `=` would be sufficient. And it would be a thousand times better to just have two facts, `male(john). male(dexter).` and call it a day. Please read a book and/or the documentation for your system, this is material from page two of every book.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. You need to wortk through a basic tutorial on Prolog and get a decent introductory text book and read through the starter material. You're trying to use Prolog like C or other imperative language and it just doesn't work that way. In this particular case, if you look up what `==/2` means, you'll find that `X == john` fails because `john` is an atom, and `X` is an uninstantiated variable. So they don't match. `==/2` is **not** the *unification* operator.

Comment: Did my answer help you.? @raj

Comment: Yes, your answer really helped me @jay Joshi!

Comment: I am happy to help you :) Please tick it as answer if you like. It will help others. and so other user also know that question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem:

There is no operator like double equal to ( == ) in prolog. It will give unexpected outputs.

#### Solution:

Use only Equal to ( = ) for the comparison.!

#### Code

```
male(X):-
       X = 'john'.
male(X):-
       X = 'dexter'.
```

It is not advisable to use OR operator in Prolog.

references:

- [Facts, Rules, Goals and Queries in Prolog](http://www.ablmcc.edu.hk/%7Escy/prolog/pro02.htm)
- [Comparison Operators in Prolog](http://cs.union.edu/%7Estriegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node42.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
string1(progga).
string2(ikra).

go:-
write("Enter your name"),
nl,
read(X),nl,
string1(Y),
X=@=Y,nl, write("Matched");
write("not Matched"),go2.

/*Another way to*/
go2:-                
string1(A),
string2(B),
A=@=B,nl, write("Matched");
write("not Matched").
```